# How do you create a class so that it returns __new__ but you can still access the class's property, not the returned object?

Tags: python, class

How do you create a class so that it returns **new** but you can still access the class's property, not the returned object?

Like for example :

```
class myClass:
  myProperty = "This is the myClass property."

  def __new__(self):
    return list("Hello World")

print(myClass().myProperty)
```

How do I do this so that `.myProperty` isnt directing on the returned list of `__new__`?, because im always getting an error that says there isnt an attribute or function of a list.

Comment: You want, given `x=myClass()`, for `x.myProperty` to **not** look for that attribute on `x`?

Comment: this makes *no sense*.

Comment: For sraters, you will not be able to access the property from the object returned from `myClass`, this is because you return a `list` object. Of course, you can always access `myClass`.

Comment: Why would `__new__` ever return something other than the object itself? I can think of no scenario where there would ever be any reason to ever do that.

Comment: Why not just `__init__(self) ... self.myProperty = "foo"`?

Comment: @dmedine that won't work. For starters, `__init__` will not be called. But if it was, then `self` would be a `list` object, and doing `self.myProperty = "foo"` would raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, well, you would have to change the way the class was instantiated as well. I also assumed that `__new__` would be removed entirely. I don't really understand the question, though. Or is python so crazy that you can inherit from a superclass just by returning that type from a constructor? Wow.

Comment: Why did you *make* an instance (of `list`, or any other class) if you don't want to use it?

Comment: @BloxyBloxy no, it doesn't make any sense. You can always access the class property doing `myClass.myProperty`. You will never be able to access the property through the instance returned by `myClass()`, though, since **it is not an instance of `myClass`**. IOW, `isinstance(myClass(), myClass)` is **false**. This is why this makes no sense.

Comment: @dmedine I don't really understand what you are asking. Note, the instance returned by `myClass()` **does not inherit from `myClass`**. So no, you cannot effect inheritance this way, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The newly created object by myClass prevents me from accessing a property from myClass, because Python sees it that im accessing a method or property from the new object returned by myClass. The aim here Juanpa, is that im creating a new object from myClass while also trying to access a property from myClass, Not the created object from myClass. Therefore Juanpa, this question completely makes sense, and the answer below does address the question im asking.

Comment: @BloxyBloxy I don't know how to be any more clear, or what precisely it is you don't understand. The result of the expression `myClass()` will be a `list` object. You cannot simultaneously make it so it is a `list` object **and** you can access a property that doesn't belong to `list` (or any class it's it's MRO). What you are asking for **makes no sense**. The answer below amounts to **just defining your class as `class myClass: pass`. So none of this makes sense. If you want to access the class property, use `myClass.myProperty`.

Comment: Wow... someone with no reputation whatsoever asking a Python gold badge holder if they are unfamiliar with Python, while misunderstanding the basics of Python object model.... amazing... You might want to accept helpful criticism a bit more humbly. This is a quintessential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Any reason you are not subclassing `list`? Or, if that is not available for some reason, proxying to `list`?

Comment: As long as you return `list` from `__new__`, it is a `list`, with `list` members (and only `list` members). There is _no way_ to add an attribute to a `list` instance, whether you create it directly as a list, or return a list from `myClass.__new__`. Only an instance of a class with `myClass` as one of its ancestors, or an instance of a class which overrides `__getattr__` to dynamically access `myClass.myProperty`, can handle it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just tested out this whole code, and the list object has no attribute called "myProperty". Im getting this error, does this question make sense now?

Comment: @Amadan , If that first comment was targeted at me, maybe ask yourself if sarcasm is an efficient way to tell someone that they are doing something wrong. Especially when you're assuming I'm trying to earn a Python gold badge holder. I was quite humble as I was just trying calmly prove my point about how this question in my point of view makes sense.

Comment: @BloxyBloxy look, I never claimed *otherwise*. Indeed, I've explained to you *why* the error occurs, and *why* what you are asking makes no sense. Want a solution? Just delete your definition of `__new__`. Of course then, `myClass()` won't be a `list`. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: " If your unfamiliar with python 3, I suggest staying out of this thread.". juanpa.arrivillaga has been on Stack Overflow answering Python questions for better part of 8 years, and has gold badges to prove it. I was simply saying this is uncalled for.

Comment: So then, how do I get a class to represent an object? I tried __repr__, but It only represents it when print() is used.

Comment: @BloxyBloxy "how do I get a class to represent an object" **what does that mean precisely**? What do you mean by "represent"? What, precisely, is the *behavior* you are trying to achieve? This entire time, you haven't actually *explained what you are trying to accomplish*. Why did you override `__new__` to begin with? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Amadan , You might want to consider avoiding statements like "Wow..." or "amazing..." when trying to imply that what I said was uncalled for. Because sarcasm is certainly not 'simply saying this is uncalled for.' as it brings more of a negative attitude and non-constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

As I (and others) said in the comment, what you are doing can't work as long as you are returning a `list`. If you subclass `list`, or if you proxy it, you can do something similar to what you are asking (hopefully).

As a subclass, the object naturally has access to any properties defined on its class, as well as any ancestor class; there is no need to override `__new__`, as this is the normal way OOP works:

```
class ListSubClass(list):
    prop = "a list with a prop"

s = ListSubClass()
print(isinstance(s, list))
# => true
s.append(3); print(s)
# => [3]
print(s.prop)
# => "a list with a prop"
```

If you really need to override `__new__` for some reason, you can do it like this (thanks to Davis Herring for the reminder), though as it stands it is equivalent to the previous code:

```
class ListSubClassWithOverriddenNew(list):
    prop = "a list with a prop"

    def __new__(cls):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj
```

Using a proxy (with `wrapt` library, for ease of use), you can implement added functionality, while passing any other method/property lookups to the wrapped object:

```
import wrapt

class ProxyWhichAddsProp(wrapt.ObjectProxy):
    prop = "a list with a prop"

class ListProxy:
    def __new__(self):
        a_list = list()
        a_list_with_prop = ProxyWhichAddsProp(a_list)
        return a_list_with_prop

p = ListProxy()

print(isinstance(p, list))
# => true
p.append(3); print(p)
# => [3]
print(p.prop)
# => "a list with a prop"
```

Comment: You can certainly create an instance of a type that overrides `__new__` with `object.__new__(cls)` (or, better, `super().__new__(cls)` in the class).

Comment: @DavisHerring Oh right, good point!

Answer (score -2):

In Python, the behavior you're describing can be achieved by overriding the **init** method of your class instead of the **new** method. The **init** method is responsible for initializing the object after it has been created, while the **new** method is responsible for creating the object itself.

```
class myClass:
    myProperty = "This is the myClass property."

    def __init__(self):
        self.myData = list("Hello World")

# Create an instance of myClass
obj = myClass()

# Access the myProperty attribute
print(obj.myProperty)

# Access the myData attribute (which is assigned in __init__)
print(obj.myData)
```

In this example, the myProperty attribute is a class-level attribute, and you can access it on instances of the class. The myData attribute is assigned within the **init** method and can also be accessed on instances of the class.

By using the **init** method to assign attributes to the instance, you can avoid the confusion caused by returning a different object from the **new** method and still access the class's properties as expected.

Comment: this doesn't address the question at all

Comment: Ok great!, so If i can now access the class property, how do I now access the created instance by __new__, outside the class?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, This completely addresses the question, as the solution was to create an instance outside of the class using super().

Comment: @BloxyBloxy: But now you don't have the list, plus the `__new__` override isn't doing anything any more, plus the suggestion about "moving" `myProperty` out of `__new__` isn't actually a *change* to the original code, which already had `myProperty` outside of `__new__`. juanpa.arrivillaga is right.